# Select a cataloging / metadata system?

Tags: metadata, geoserver, catalog, geonetwork, georchestra

We are setting up a GIS server based on qgis / postgresql-postgis and geoserver.
We are missing an important tool, the cataloging and metadata system.

Postgresql and geoserver are on a windows server 2019 virtual server.

We are GIS & geomatics people but not computer scientists. We are therefore looking for an opensource solution that is relatively easy to install and configure, which does not require extensive computer skills.
What solutions do you think would be suitable? We have identified :

1. Geonetwork,
2. Georchestra https://www.georchestra.org/software.html
3. Geonode

Are there others?
Among these 3 solutions, would there be one easier to set and use, which would be functional on both linux and windows?
Are there other criteria to take into account in our selection of technology?

Thank you very much for your help, recommendation and / or feedback.

Answer (score 0):

GeoNetwork might be the silver bullet (though it tends to do more than the job, since it also features an integrated geodata viewer).

geOrchestra provides both GeoServer and GeoNetwork, and a Single Sign On feature. It also provides additional modules like a user management console, a data upload tool ("datafeeder"), analytics, mapstore and so on. It's very modular and leaves plenty of room for integration.

GeoNode provides a fully integrated environment. It's like a social network dedicated to data. It's also based on GeoServer and has a SSO.

None of the above are easy to setup & maintain if you do not have basic computer skills. With a docker composition, you may have one of them running pretty quickly though.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use [Cartoview](https://cartoview.net/) which is an extension of GeoNode, visualizing the layers and maps in geospatial apps. It can be used in different environments (Linux, Windows, macOS).

You can download the windows installer from the link above and give it a try!